# Input string not correct in format in webform addition

Tags: c#, webforms

When i add total input textbox value and want to show all total textbox values in another textBox SubTotal why does it show error

> input string not in correct format

```
string[] arr = new string[4];
arr[0] = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
arr[1] = textBox1Price.Text;
arr[2] = textBox2Qty.Text;
arr[3] = textBoxTotal.Text;

ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(arr);
listView1.Items.Add(item);

if (textBoxSubTotal.Text == "" || textBoxSubTotal.Text != "")
{
    textBoxSubTotal.Text = (Convert.ToInt16(textBoxTotal.Text) + 
                            Convert.ToInt16(textBoxSubTotal.Text)).ToString();
}
```

it should show all total values in subTotal textbox

[image]

Comment: `if (textBoxSubTotal.Text == "" || textBoxSubTotal.Text != "")` this condition will be **always** true Kindly show us what values you entered in `textBoxTotal` and in `textBoxSubTotal` text box

Comment: in textBoxTotal field all total values like 400,500,600 i want to sum these total in another textbox textBoxSubTotal textbox

Comment: Do you want to say you have `textBoxTotal.Text = "400, 500, 600"` and you want to store `textBoxSubTotal.Text = (400 + 500 + 600)`?

Comment: i also add image above please see

Comment: yes i want this type of result

Comment: What line is the error on? Can you please rewrite the start of the question? It does not make sense and is hard to understand.

Comment: error line is input string is not in valid format for Subboxtotal textbox field

Comment: i want like in picture when all totals are added it should be show in subtotal in subtotal box

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this.

```
int GetSum(IEnumerable<string> data) 
    => data.Select( txt => { int.TryParse(txt, out var m); return m;}).Sum();
```

## Example

```
Console.WriteLine(GetSum(new [] { "100", "200", "xxx" })); //300

Console.WriteLine(GetSum(new [] { "100", "200", "300" })); //600
```

or

```
targetComboBox.Text = GetSum( new []{combo1.Text, combo2.Text, ...})?.ToString();
```

## Null if any is null?

```
int? GetSum(IEnumerable<string> data) 
    => data.Select( txt => int.TryParse(txt, out var m) is var b && b ? m : (int?)null) is var parsed 
    && parsed.Any(i => i == null) 
        ? null 
        : parsed.Sum();

Console.WriteLine(GetSum(new [] { "100", "200", "xxx" })); //null

Console.WriteLine(GetSum(new [] { "100", "200", "300" })); //600
```